# Multivariable lookup in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have my macro lookup two values and then return the currency amount from an external sheet.  The sheet is supposed to pull the data from "NPR" and put it into the defined cell in main but the only way I can get it to function is with entering the formula into the selected cells.  This is a fine way to do it but I would like it to be cleaner than this.  I have tried it two ways:

This comes up with error 1004, user defined or variable defined error.

```
Cells(3, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("NPR").Range(Cells(1, 14), Cells(44, 14)), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Main").Cells(3, 1) & Sheets("Main").Cells(3, 2), Sheets("NPR").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(44, 1)) & Sheets("NPR").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(44, 2))))
```

Or:

```
Range("C3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("NPR").Range("N1:N44"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Main").Range("A3") & Sheets("Main").Range("B3"), Sheets("NPR").Range("A1:A44") & Sheets("NPR").Range("B1:B44")))
```

Which gives me Error 13, Excel VBA Type mismatch.  I would like to be able to use the first one in a loop to rotate through multiple items once I get this going.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to adapt a difficult array style worksheet formula and VBA is choking on it. Here are three alternate methods using the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to supply the row numnber to the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, app As Application

Set app = Application
Set ws = Worksheets("NPR")

With Worksheets("Main")
    'method 1
    .Cells(3, 3) = [INDEX(NPR!N1:N44, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:44)/(NPR!A1:A44=Main!A3)*(NPR!B1:B44=Main!B3), 1))]
    'method 2
    .Cells(3, 3) = app.Evaluate("INDEX(NPR!N1:N44, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:44)/(NPR!A1:A44=Main!A3)*(NPR!B1:B44=Main!B3), 1))")
    'method 3
    .Cells(3, 3).Formula = "=INDEX(NPR!N1:N44, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:44)/(NPR!A1:A44=Main!A3)*(NPR!B1:B44=Main!B3), 1))"
    .Cells(3, 3) = .Cells(3, 3).Value
End With

Set ws = Nothing
Set app = Nothing
```

Your original formula was not using an exact match for the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca)'s **[match_type]** optional parameter but I've indferred that was the intention by the nature of the formula.

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>